# SQL Server how to round money variable up if decimal part is the same or greater than 0.5

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable @value with type `money` and need to round it up if it's the same or greater than 0.5 and down otherwise. Some examples:

```
2.5 --> 3
2.4999 --> 2
2.5001 --> 3
2.4 --> 2
2.7 --> 3
```

Comment: Fortunately the designers of T-SQL were not unnecessarily imaginative when they named the [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROUND()` function to do so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cash (val MONEY);

INSERT INTO cash (val)
VALUES (2.5), (2.4999), (2.5001), (2.4), (2.7);

SELECT *, CAST(ROUND(val, 0) AS INT)
FROM cash;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2640c/1)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a function for rounding that just wraps the `round(@var, 1)` but when I set the parameter as `money` it doesn't round, I have to set it as `int` but I actually pass a `money` variable, why is that?

Comment: Err, that needs more details. This answers your current question only. : )